# How to push a new value to an array if the current value is an array or set the value as an array if it is not in a single MongoDB Query

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a project where we have been using simple, unversioned values for documents:

```js
{
  _id: <someid>,
  prop1: 'foo',
  prop2: 'bar',
  prop3: 'baz'
}
```

I would like to update the method that saves prop values to start saving values as versions in an array, to look like this:

```
{
  _id: <someid>,
  prop1: [{ value: 'foo', createdAt: <someDate>}],
  prop2: [{ value: 'bar', createdAt: <someDate>}, { value: 'barrrrr', createdAt: <someDate>}],
  prop3: 'baz'
}
```

I would like, in my update query, to `$push` the new prop value object *if* it's already an array, or to `$set` it to `[{ value: 'newvalue', createdAt: +new Date()}] if not. Ideally, this would let me seamlessly transition the data to be versioned over time. On the retrieval side, if it's not an array we just treat the only value that's there as the reference version, and whenever anything gets updated, that prop is converted to the new format.

I've been struggling to find an example of that same use case: can anyone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

After being pointed in the right direction, I was able to use the aggregation pipeline in combination with update to do what I wanted. Part of the key was to abandon trying to pivot between setting and pulling--instead, I could use the helper method `$concatArrays` to accomplish the array addition a different way. Here's the basic shell code I got to work, purely to show the structure:

```js
db.test.docs.update({ key: 2 }, [
  {
    $set: {
      prop2: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $isArray: '$prop2' },
          then: {
            $concatArrays: [
              '$prop2',
              [
                {
                  value: 'CONCAT!'
                }
              ]
            ]
          },
          else: [
            {
              value: 'SET!'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB 4.2 you can use the pipeline form of update to use aggregation stages and operators to do that.

You would likely need to use `$cond` and `$type` to find out if the field already contains an array, and then `$concatArrays` to combine the values.

Comment: Thanks—you were able to get me pointed in the right direction. I'm including example code of what I got to work as an edit to my question.